# I don't know how to make a random number of 0,1,2 appear as rock, paper, and sissors when printing the result sentence

Tags: c

I just started learning programming, so I'm not good enough.
I'd appreciate it if someone could help me:)

**Question : Two random values should be made to play a total 10 times of rock-scissors-paper games and produce the following results.**

### Here is example result.

The 1 th game was won by the computer
(computer = sissors, player = paper)

The 2 th game was won by the player
(computer = paper, player = sissors)

The 3 th game was a draw
(computer = sissors, player = sissors)

......

The 10 th game ~

### This is the code I write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
 // 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=sissors
 // c = computer , p = player
 
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
 int c; 
 int p;

 c = rand() % 3;
 p = rand() % 3;
 
 sprintf (rock, "%d", 0);
 sprintf (paper, "%d", 1);
 sprintf (sissors, "%d", 2);


 if (c == p)
 {
     printf("The %d th game was a draw \n", i+1);
     printf("      (computer = %s, player = %s)",c,p);
 }
 
 else if ((c == 0 && p == 2) || (c == 1 && p == 0) || (c == 2) && (p == 1));
     {
         printf("The %d th game was won by the computer. \n", i+1);
         printf("      (computer = %s, player = %s\n)",c,p);
     }
    
 else
    {
     printf("The %d th game was won by the player \n", i+1);
     printf("      (computer = %s, player = %s\n)",c,p);
    }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know how to use `if` and variables, how would you combine those skills to get the right content into a variable? A good type for a string variable would be something like `const char *`. Or did you know you can print part of a line using printf? Just don't end the format with `\n`. This can once again be combined with `if`s to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, and I think its an elegant solution. By defining the outcome table, you can get the text accordingly.

```
static const int outcome[3][3] =
{
    { 0, 2, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 2 },
    { 2, 1, 0 }
};

static const char * signs[3] =
{
    "rock",
    "paper",
    "scissors"
};

static const char * texts[3] =
{
    "was a draw",
    "was won by the player",
    "was won by the computer"
};

int main()
{
    //<..>

    printf("The %i th game %s (computer = %s, player = %s)\n", i+1, texts[outcome[p][c]], signs[c], signs[p]);

    //<..>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could've just stored the three possible outcomes as a single *2D character array* or as a `const char *` mentioned by @dratenik in the comments. I used a *2D array* just to make the approach simple:

```
char r[3][7]={"Rock","Paper","Scissor"};
```

As for the `for loop`, I'd change your last *else if* statement to something like this:

```
else if((c==0 && p==2)||(c==1 && p==0)||(c==2 && p==1))
```

instead of what you did:

```
else if ((c == 0 && p == 2) || (c == 1 && p == 0) || (c == 2) && (p == 1));
```

Note that, here, we're dealing with cases like `A or B or C or....` where each event `A` comprises of further cases `a and b and c and...`. In your case, what you did meant something like `A or B or C and D`. Learn how to use the brackets in `C` and also about [Semicolons in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#Programming).

Finally, the `printf` statement of the **above** `else if` part (did not abide by your specified format, but you can edit that):

```
printf("Computer: %s\nPlayer: %s\nComputer wins\n",r[c],r[p]);
```